# astropy.convolution.convolve returns nan values

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, astropy

I am trying to use the astropy module to smooth my data. As a 1D example I have tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy import convolution as conv
var1=np.arange(10)
kernel=np.asarray([-1,1,0])
conv.convolve(var1,kernel)
```

This returns in my case: `array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])`

I assumed that it should return `array([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])`. I have tried using for var1 datatypes uint8, int8 and float32. I have also tried using `convolve_fft`, with the same result.

I am familiar with the convolution filter of scipy but I want to use astropy for when NaN values are actually present in my data, so as to smooth them over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel sums to zero and hence, `astropy` will raise the warning

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide kernel_internal /= kernel_sum
```

which eventually leads to all the `nans`.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but why would it sum to zero? If i just take the first three elements of var1 i get [-1,1,0]*[0,1,2], which is -1*0+ 1*1 +0*2 = 1

Comment: Your kernel itself sums to zero, `sum([-1, 1, 0]) = 0`. Because the kernel is normalised by its sum, you get a kernel full of `nans` and thus a convolved array full of `nans`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this normalization. This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out it's because the sum of your kernel is zero:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sum(kernel)  # kernel = np.asarray([-1,1,0])
0
```

That itself wouldn't be a problem if one doesn't normalize the `kernel` but [`astropy.convolution.convolve`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.convolution.convolve.html#astropy.convolution.convolve) always normalizes the kernel to interpolate over `NaN` (since astropy 1.3 also masked) values in the array and multiplies the result again by the sum of the original kernel (except you explicitly use `normalize_kernel=True`).

---

Even though you already stated that you're familiar with it you can always use [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy-ndimage-filters-convolve):

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage import convolve

>>> convolve(var1, kernel[::-1])  # var1=np.arange(10)
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

and do the interpolation and convolution and the `NaN` positions yourself! (Not really nice but with a zero-sum, assymetric and mixed signed kernel you can't properly do a convolvution).

However, you need to reverse (thus the `[::-1]`) the kernel when using [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy).

In your case you could also simply use [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) (which drops the leading zero):

```
>>> np.diff(var1)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```